# Running a function before opening/finding a file

Tags: emacs, elisp

Im trying to make a function that should run before a file is opened/shown in the buffer. This function really only needs to run once.

I try to set a mode depending on the content of the file that is about to be viewed. I know about `add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist <filename-regexp> . <mode>`

But this is not enough. Ideally i would want to parse the file (or just a small part of it) and check the file content before setting the mode. Usually the view-file (think .js/.php etc. in a mvc framework) has the same extension as the files in "pure" code, so i cant just check for the file extension.

Why?

Basically when using any template language i normally want to use `web-mode` and when doing "pure" code i want to use the mode for the language.

So basically i would want to parse the file before, and check for some regexp, and if it matches i would set `web-mode` and if not i would set the language-mode i want to use.

I know i can easily change modes manually, but i would rather have this done by Emacs.

Comment: What @sds said. You can also look at file handlers - see the Elisp manual about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `magic-mode-alist` for that.  You'll probably want to use a MATCH-FUNCTION which checks the buffer's file-name and its content.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your function into [`find-file-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html).
When it is run, the `major-mode` is already set, but you can change it.

If you own the file in question, you might also want to explore [file variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).